# checked Attribute prevents to change location to pathname

Tags: javascript, html

I need a button that re-direct the user to the same page he is in but without the querystring.

So, after using input and send the GET request, like

```
www.example.com?id=5
```

This button needs to send the user to `www.example.com`. (NB I don't want `<a href="">` tags)

I tried:

in html
`<button onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">Reset Data</button>`

then in JS

`$('button').click(function(){  window.location = window.location.pathname})`

But nothing. I found interesting that the last attempt work in the js console but in the normal script the page is simply refreshed (query string included)

**EDIT**

Link to example:

**https://eaaqdev01.cloudapp.net/test3.html**

To simulate what my server code does I have hard-coded this

`<input type="checkbox" name="TBRsubpots[]" value="Other" checked>`

i.e. the above imput will be already checked. Basically the user, after submitting, will see the inputs he checked as already checked (like the above). Without this it would work, as you can see at

**https://eaaqdev01.cloudapp.net/test4.html**

Comment: `<button onclick="window.location = window.location.pathname">Reset Data</button>` seems to work for me in IE. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hm, seems to work for me in Chrome too. Do you have a page somewhere where we can see the issue in action?

Comment: @JLRishe no unfortunately. I'll double check if some server-side code is not doing something I am not aware of... and edit with more details

Comment: I'd also suggest having a look in a packet sniffer such as Fiddler. You might find for whatever reason that the server is sending redirects from the non-querystring url to the one with the querystring.

Comment: *I don't want `<a href="">` tags* — Why not? They are the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Quentin I don't like having always to remove its ugly style, and also I just want to understand why I can't without them :-)

Comment: @JLRishe I've edited with a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a `button` element acts as a submit button unless you specify otherwise in its `type` attribute. So it is causing your form to be submitted and essentially your changes to `window.location` are having no effect.

This should work:

```
<button type="button"
        onclick="window.location = window.location.pathname;">reset</button>
```

or this:

```
<button onclick="return void(window.location = window.location.pathname);">reset</button>
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to go the nicer, unobtrusive route:

```
$('button').click(function(e) { 
     e.preventDefault(); 
     window.location = window.location.pathname; 
});
```

Which is what I think most people would recommend nowadays. It would still be a good idea to put a `type="button"` attribute on it in any case.

See also the info on the type attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Thanks. Also or the links. It says `type reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.` Is it what I was after?

Answer (score 1):

give it a try

```
window.location.href.split("?")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 <button onclick="location.search='';">Reset Data</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but it simply re-loads the page. the querystring is still there

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> $(location).attr('href').substr(0,$(location).attr('href').indexOf('?')-1)